# Testing a General Linear Hypothesis in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, hypothesis-test

I'm working my way through a Linear Regression Textbook and am trying to replicate the results from a section on the Test of the General Linear Hypothesis, but I need a little bit of help on how to do so in R.

I've already taken a look at a number of other posts, but am hoping someone can give me some example code. I have data on twenty-six subjects which has the following form:

```
Group, Weight (lb), HDL Cholesterol mg/decaliters  
1,163.5,75  
1,180,72.5  
1,178.5,62  
2,106,57.5  
2,134,49  
2,216.5,74  
3,163.5,76  
3,154,55.5  
3,139,68
```

Given this data I am trying to test to see if the regression lines fit to the three groups of subjects have a common slope. The models postulated are:

```
y=βo + β1⋅x + ϵ  
y=γ0 + γ1⋅xi + ϵ  
y= δ0 + δ1⋅xi + ϵ
```

So the hypothesis of interest is H0: β1 = γ1 = δ1

I have been trying to do this using the linearHypothesis function in the car library, but have been having trouble knowing what the model object should be, and am not confident that this is the correct approach (or package) to be using.

Any help would be much appreciated – Thanks!

Comment: If you need help with a statical method for a given statistical hypothesis, you should use the statistical Q&A site [stats.se]. You need to decide what method you want to use before it becomes a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Tim, your question doesn't seem so much to be about R code. Instead, it appears that you have questions about how to test the interaction of your `Group` and `Weight (lb)` variables on the outcome `HDL Cholesterol mg/decaliters`. You don't state this specifically, but I'm taking a guess that these are your predictors and outcome, respectively.

So essentially, you're trying to see if the predictor `Weight (lb)` has differential effects depending on the level of the variable `Group`. This can be done in a number of ways using the linear model. A simple regression approach would be `lm(hdl ~ 1 + group + weight + group*weight)`. And then the coefficient for the interaction term `group*weight` would tell you whether or not there is a significant interaction (i.e., moderation) effect.

However, I think we would have a major concern. In particular, we ought to worry that our hypothesized effect is that the `group` variable and the `hdl` variable *do not* interact. That is, you're essentially predicting the null. Furthermore, you're predicting the null despite having a small sample size. Therefore, it would be rather unlikely that we have sufficient statistical power to detect an effect, even if there were one to be observed.

Comment: Thanks–I'm afraid it seems my question wasn't clear enough, I'll edit it to make it clearer.